# Books on mathematical frameworks?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, mathematical-modeling

I am a first year student of applied mathematics. I currently find myself always trying to explain any phenomenon with mathematical models- the few ones (models) that I encountered till now. I always try to fit phenomenas to models like a data scientist does when he fits data to models.
Recently I found this book:

[Robert B. Banks
Growth and Diffusion Phenomena: Mathematical Frameworks and Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540555072)

This book is different from other applied mathematics books in the sense that it focuses on a particular model unlike others that try to model the whole world in a single book.
It particularly focuses on growth and diffusion phenomena. Which is , to me , great because this book studies these two models in great detail rather than just stating many models on the surface level.
I also found some book that is specific to some single phenomenon like this book on Hysteresis
[Mathematical Models of Hysteresis and their Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B012YSH24M)

Can someone please recommend to me some books like these that describes a certain phenomena or discusses a certain mathematical framework to study in detail and apply some phenomena?
Any book that discusses and models in detail some phenomena: could be growth,could be decline, could be (what happens in the limiting case)- type of thing,  could be something else, could be anything...

Answer (score 2):

There is a hidden gem I read during my PhD study, and it is co-authored by Lions (founding father of many methods in my field and still serves as my bread and butter).

- Duvant, G., & Lions, J. L. *Inequalities in mechanics and physics*. 1976.

It is like an encyclopedia of PDE models used in physics and mechanics. However, it is not for beginners, but rather an extremely good reference book for research.